# Cannot upload photo using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to automate filling a form using selenium and python. Everything seems to work except uploading an image by clicking the Add Photo button. Here is the html snippet of the button:

```
<div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;" class="image-uploader-button-wrap">
    <input style="left: -1000px; top: 0px; position: absolute;" name="Filedata" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" id="imageUploader_1" type="file">
    <input class="olx-upload-button" value="Add photos" type="button">
</div>
```

I tried two different approaches (none of which i got to work :( ):
1)

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("imageUploader_1")
elem.send_keys("/Users/ue/Desktop/703.png")
```

But this gave me the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with' ;
```

2) Second approach:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("olx-upload-button").click()
```

This opens a Windows popup window and I CANNOT find a way to select image from my local directory (Desktop) and select Open on the Window pop-up. 
After the popup window, I tried to do:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("imageUploader_1").send_keys("/Users/ue/Desktop/703.png")
```

But nothing happened. I have looked at almost every post on SO and i am pretty sure I am one step away from fixing. Any idea/suggestions/tips would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `overflow: hidden` and/or using `JavascriptExecutor`.

Selenium decides whether an element is shown or not on following criteria (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/javascript/atoms/dom.js):

> - Option or optgroup is shown iff enclosing select is shown (ignoring the select's opacity).
> - Image map elements are shown if image that uses it is shown, and the area of the element is positive.
> - Any hidden input is not shown.
> - Any NOSCRIPT element is not shown.
> - Any element with hidden visibility is not shown.
> - Any element with a display style equal to 'none' or that has an ancestor
> - with display style equal to 'none' is not shown.
> - Any transparent element is not shown.
> - Any element without positive size dimensions is not shown.
> - A vertical or horizontal SVG Path element will report zero width or height but is "shown" if it has a positive stroke-width.
> - Zero-sized elements should still be considered to have positive size if they have a child element or text node with positive size, unless
>     the element has an 'overflow' style of 'hidden'.
> - Elements that are hidden by overflow are not shown.

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply but how do i delete overflow hidden? this is pre-defined in the html of the webpage....i did not create it.

Comment: anyone can help me with this one?? still stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you find your answer ? You would have to unhide before clicking.

`elem = driver.find_element_by_id('imageUploader_1')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].type = 'file';", elem)
elem.send_keys("/Users/ue/Desktop/703.png")`

Tell me if it works !